# java regex : getting a substring from a string which can vary

Tags: regex

I have a String like - `"Bangalore,India=Karnataka"`. From this String I would like to extract only the substring `"Bangalore"`. In this case the regex can be - `(.+),.*=.*`. But the problem is, the String can sometimes come like only `"Bangalore"`. Then in that case the above regex wont work. What will be the regex to get the substring `"Bangalore"` whatever the String be ?

Comment: In what way is "Athlone" a substring of "Bangalore,India=Karnataka"?

Comment: sorry it would be "Bangalore". printing mistake

Comment: Before you know how to write a regex, you must know all possible string formats. Can you please list them formally here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(.+?)(?:,.*?)?=.*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Begining of the string
  (             # begining of capture group 1
    .+?         # one or more any char non-greedy
  )             # end of group 1
  (?:           # beginig of NON capture group
    ,           # a comma
    .*?         # 0 or more any char non-greedy
  )?            # end of non capture group, optional
  =             # equal sign
  .*            # 0 or more any char
$               # end of string
```

**Updated**:
I thougth OP have to match `Bangalore,India=Karnataka` or `Bangalore=Karnataka` but as farr as I understand it is `Bangalore,India=Karnataka` or `Bangalore` so the regex is much more simpler :

```
^([^,]+)
```

This will match, at the begining of the string, one or more non-comma character and capture them in group 1.

Comment: well, that was what the OP asked for ;-)

Comment: This is working fine when the String is ""Bangalore,India=Karnataka" but is not working when the String is only ""Bangalore"

Comment: @titorcks: I missunderstood your question. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
matcher.matches()
```

tries to match against the *entire* input string. Look at the javadoc for java.util.regex.Matcher. You need to use:

```
matcher.find()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you somehow forced to solve this using one regexp and nothing else? (Stupid interview question? Extremely inflexible external API?) In general, don't try to make regexes do what plain old programming constructs do better. Just use the obvious regex, and it it doesn't match, return the entire string instead.

Comment: Yeah actually I have to send this info to a Java code which will match this with the info it already has and I am forced to do it using regex  :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested to check that "Bangalore" is contained in the string then you don't need a regexp for this.

Python:

```
In [1]: s = 'Bangalorejkdjiefjiojhdu'

In [2]: 'Bangalore' in s
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: I need to provide this info to a Java code and that has to be done using regexp

Comment: explain, you need to deliver the string "Bangalore", in what way does that string differ when extracted using regexp from standard programming constructs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, This will grab any grouping of characters at the start followed by a comma but not the comma itself.

^.*(?=,)

Comment: This is working fine when the String is ""Bangalore,India=Karnataka" but is not working when the String is only ""Bangalore"

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want a regex that matches ANY char and a SPECIFIC group of chars in the SAME expression?!  What you want is logically impossible for the same expression.

Comment: No I always want the regex to match "Bangalore" but the input String can come either as "Bangalore,India=Karnataka" or only as "Bangalore"