# regex and java : Generating a regex for a String

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java regex : getting a substring from a string which can vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030109/java-regex-getting-a-substring-from-a-string-which-can-vary)

Hi,

I have an input String as - `"Bangalore,Karnataka=India"`. Sometimes the String can come as - `"Bangalore"` only. I would always like to get the String - `"Bangalore"`whatever the input String be. I am using a regex - `"^(\w+)"`.

When I am using this regex and the input String and using any online regex tool, it is returning `"Bangalore"` fine. But when I am putting it in the java code, its failing.

The code that I am using -:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexTester {
public static void main (String [] args)
   {
     String str = "Bangalore,India=Karnataka";
     String regexpr = "^(\\w+)";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexpr);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
     if (matcher.matches()) {
         final String result = matcher.group(1);
         System.out.println(result);
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("failed");
     }
   }
}
```

The output is coming as - failed

Can anyone